# Python pip Install failing with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyexpat' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Complete Docker file: https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/master/3.8/bullseye/Dockerfile
Docker file :

'''

```
ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION 22.0.4
#https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/365
ENV PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION 57.5.0
#https://github.com/pypa/get-pip
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/aeca83c7ba7f9cdfd681103c4dcbf0214f6d742e/public/get-pip.py
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256 d0b5909f3ab32dae9d115aa68a4b763529823ad5589c56af15cf816fca2773d6

RUN set -eux; 
    wget -O get-pip.py "$PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL"; 
    echo "$PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256 *get-pip.py" | sha256sum -c -; \
    export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1; \
    python get-pip.py \
        --disable-pip-version-check \
        --no-cache-dir \
        --no-compile \
        "pip==$PYTHON_PIP_VERSION" \
        "setuptools==$PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION" ;\
        rm -f get-pip.py; \
        pip --version
```

'''
Error:
'''

```
>     python get-pip.py --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --no-compile pip==22.0.4 setuptools==57.5.0
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "get-pip.py", line 32098, in <module>
>         main()
>         File "get-pip.py", line 135, in main
>         bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
>     File "get-pip.py", line 111, in bootstrap
>         monkeypatch_for_cert(tmpdir)
>     File "get-pip.py", line 92, in monkeypatch_for_cert
>         from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
>     File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
>     File "/tmp/tmpiqi24qri/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 16, in <module>
>     File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
>     File "/tmp/tmpiqi24qri/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 21, in <module>
>     File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
>     File "/tmp/tmpiqi24qri/pip.zip/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line
> 33, in <module>
>     File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
>     File "/tmp/tmpiqi24qri/pip.zip/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
>     File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
>     File "/tmp/tmpiqi24qri/pip.zip/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 42, in <module>
>     File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
>     File "/tmp/tmpiqi24qri/pip.zip/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py",
> line 39, in <module>
>     File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
>     File "/tmp/tmpiqi24qri/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 16, in <module>
>     File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
>     File "/tmp/tmpiqi24qri/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 83, in <module>
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 138, in <module>
>         from xml.parsers import expat
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
>         from pyexpat import *
>     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyexpat'
```

'''
Trying to add python 3.8 to my custom image. I could install python 3.8.13. I am adding above lines to docker file to install pip but getting above error of 'pyexpat' module missing.

How do I add this module, do I have to install some package at OS level?

Comment: Can you extend this to a complete minimal example. Post all relevant parts of your dockerfile, including the base image and how you install python, so that it can be copy/pasted to reproduce your error. Please also make sure that your posted error message is correctly formatted and readable. My tip: Copy and paste the complete error message in your question, then highlight it and select the code button. Alternatively, just put three consecutive ` before and after the error message

Comment: Here is the Complete docker file used: https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/master/3.8/bullseye/Dockerfile

Platform: x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: This needs to go in your question. Use [edit] to copy and paste it in your question

Comment: Actual issue was with python install. 
building 'pyexpat' extension
gcc -pthread -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I./Include/internal -I./Include -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/src/python/Include -I/usr/src/python -c /usr/src/python/Modules/pyexpat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/usr/src/python/Modules/pyexpat.o
^[[91m/usr/src/python/Modules/pyexpat.c:6:19: fatal error: expat.h: No such file or directory
 #include "expat.h"

Comment: We need to have libexpat1 installed to handle this dependency. I downloaded "https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/releases/download/R_2_4_8/expat-2.4.8.tar.xz and installed manually to fix this.

Comment: Don't add the answer as a comment. Always add additional information by eiditng your question and when you have found a solution, post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **expat-dev** package before running get-pip.py

```
RUN \
    set -eu; \
    apk update --no-cache; \
    apk add --no-cache \
        expat-dev \
        ;
```